# Pandas column to multiple Column using parenthesis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column like this -

```
COL A
product a [Class A], product a [Class C]
product a [Class H], product b [Class A], product b [Class B]
product c [Class C], product d [Class A]
```

Want to convert to this using pandas -

```
Class A     Class B     Class C    Class H
product a   product a   NaN        NaN
product b   product b   NaN        product a
product d   NaN         product c  NaN
```

Comment: Why does class C column has all NaN in the output? Can you explain the logic for output?

Comment: I have updated the code now. Class C will have product c in line 3. The text within square brackets is a new column and text before the square brackets will go to that column.

Comment: The first line should be `product a [Class A], product a [Class B]`, not `Class C`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input:

```
 temp = pd.DataFrame({'COL A':['product a [Class A], product a [Class C]',
                              'product a [Class H], product b [Class A], product b [Class B]',
                              'product c [Class C], product d [Class A]']})
```

Use string split opertations, first split on ',' to get the list of pair on each row and then split on '[' to get the column name & value and store them in a dictionary

```
d = {}

cnt = 0
for s in temp['COL A']:
    d[cnt] = {i.split('[')[1][:-1]:i.split('[')[0].strip() for i in s.split(',')}
    cnt += 1
```

The dictionary d:

```
{0: {'Class A': 'product a', 'Class C': 'product a'},
 1: {'Class H': 'product a', 'Class A': 'product b', 'Class B': 'product b'},
 2: {'Class C': 'product c', 'Class A': 'product d'}}
```

Then create a new dataframe from the dictionary:(used transpose to get class A and class B as columns and then used sort_index to order the column names)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d).transpose().sort_index(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
      Class A    Class B    Class C    Class H
0  product a        NaN  product a        NaN
1  product b  product b        NaN  product a
2  product d        NaN  product c        NaN
```

Comment: I keep getting this error: list index out of range

Comment: Can you post here the input in the row where you see the error

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach using [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) to bring the data into a more canonical form, then [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) the product name and class
with a regular expression (tinker with it as needed):

- `([\w\s]+)`: sequence of letters and whitespace
- `\[(.+)\]`: something in between `[]`

The final step is a basic [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to get the desired format.

```py
df2 = (df["COL A"].str.split(",")  # split into lists
       .explode()  # explode lists into rows
       .str.extract("([\w\s]+)\[(.+)\]")  # extract info
       .pivot(values=0, columns=1))  # pivot
```

**Result:**

```py
1      Class A      Class B      Class C     Class H
0   product a           NaN   product a          NaN
1   product b    product b           NaN  product a 
2   product d           NaN   product c          NaN
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Appreciate it. Going to spend sometime on these functions.